# Modular arithmetic: Reaching an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Given $n=2^w$, where $w$ is the word length.

Consider an interval $[c_1,c_2]$, where $0\leq c_1\leq c_2\leq 2^w-1$, and let the interval length be $d$. Also, consider an operation $+\delta$, where $0<\delta < n$ and is coprime with $n$. This forms finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n$, and $\delta$ is generator of this group

Now, given $x$, the problem is to obtain minimal $k$ such that $(x+k\delta)$ mod $n \in [c_1,c_2]$, when $\delta > d$

Is there a compact way to represent this in terms of $x$, $\delta$, and $d$? or how should I go about solving this?

Comment: Is the "%" a typo?

Comment: When delta is smaller than d (larger than n-d), it is straightforward and you can use dead reckoning.  If you are lucky and x is in the right residue class as one of the c's, then k will be smaller than n/delta and again you have a case of simple arithmetic to find k.  Otherwise the problem becomes figuring out how much larger than n/delta k is, and it is simple for some delta and d and more complicated for others.  Gerhard "Try Small Cases For Yourself" Paseman, 2017.10.30.

Comment: @Jules, I think that in some circles % is the standard symbol for "reduced modulo".

Comment: Sorry for the that, and I changed it, Jules Lamers. Gerhard, there is no question about $\delta \leq d$, and I've mentioned that now.

Comment: I am interesting in a similar thing, in fact I want to control in some sense how the image of the map $f_{x,\delta}: x\to x+k\delta$ is uniformly distribution in $[0,n]$. This is simple, I am considering the similar thing in higher dimension. i.e. how can we capture some information about the distribution of multi-linear map in linear space base on finite field. especially how the image of the map is uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no "compact representation" for $k$.

The problem is equivalent to the following integer linear programming problem:
$$\begin{cases} 
\text{minimize}\ k,\\
k\geq 0,\\
c_1 \leq x+k\delta + tn \leq c_2,
\end{cases}$$
where $k,t$ are integer variables.

A solution in practice can be obtained with an ILP solver. Alternatively, it can be approached via computing a [closest vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_.28CVP.29) to $\begin{bmatrix}0\\ \frac{c_1+c_2}2-x\end{bmatrix}$ in the lattice generated by the columns of
$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 0\\\delta & n\end{bmatrix}$$
under an appropriate choice of the parameter $\alpha>0$, which controls the ratio between $k$ and $|k\delta + tn + x - \frac{c_1+c_2}2|$ in the solution (notice that the latter is required to be at most $\frac{d}2$). Heuristically, one can expect $k\approx \frac{n}{d}$, and thus the optimal choice of $\alpha$ be around $\frac{d^2}{2n}$.

Comment: Here, we can impose definite bounds on the variables $t$ and $k$. Does it help?

Comment: You can add these bounds to both ILP and CVP formulations, and that may potentially improve performance and/or chances of getting the solution.